# ошибка в Unity&AdMod

Tags: c#, unity3d

Скачал версию 6.0.0 AdMod, выдаёт ошибки. Я уже попробовал: переустанавливал AdMod, перезапускал Unity.

```
[12:01:10] Assembly 'Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/Google.PackageManagerResolver_v1.2.165.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Assembly name 'Google.PackageManagerResolver' does not match file name 'Google.PackageManagerResolver_v1.2.165
[12:01:10] Assembly 'Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/Google.JarResolver_v1.2.165.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Assembly name 'Google.JarResolver' does not match file name 'Google.JarResolver_v1.2.165'
[12:01:10] Assembly 'Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/Google.IOSResolver_v1.2.165.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
[12:01:10] Assembly 'Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/Google.VersionHandlerlmpl_v1.2.165.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Assembly name 'Google.VersionHandlerlmpl' does not match file name 'Google.VersionHandlerlmpl_v1.2.165'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вот видео, где решается эта или похожая проблема: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4ERv0oLJXc&ab_channel=CodeProf